# Word for "getting something to work"

Tags: single-word-requests

In engineering contexts, one often does not actually implement a design, but rather uses an existing implementation. The process of getting an existing solution to work might require some time and effort, and I'm looking for the verb describing this effort.<sup>1</sup>

You haven't implemented anything yourself, and you're not integrating anything yet either, but this still may take up a lot of time. So, how do you describe what you're doing?

> I was busy ______ing the solution company X gave us.

<sub>1. For fellow programmers: As an example, consider getting someone else's library to compile successfully on your system.</sub>

Comment: Debugging for programmers.

Comment: So something along the lines of fitting the existing solution to the present situation?

Comment: @BleepBloopOverflow - debugging implies finding bugs which is not the case.

Comment: Usually "implementation" is the word used (and that often involves substantial debugging).  With regard to the specific case of your library, though, it would likely be "installing" or "configuring".

Comment: I might use "hacking-in". But then I'm quite derogatory about my own coding abilities.

Comment: Perfecting might work.

Comment: @nbubis Ah, so when you said getting something go work, there was an implication that it wasn't working already. Debugging seemed appropriate in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I was busy **activating** the solution*.

> activate: to make active or capable of action [CED](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/activate)

Answer (score 2):

If I were given a solution, I might **implement** it.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the level of completion of the already existing solution and the amount of work needed:

> I was busy **fine tuning** the solution
>
> I was **tuning** the solution
>
> I was busy **tweaking** the solution
>
> I was **adjusting** the solution
>
> I was **integrating** the solution (with the existing system)...
>
> I was busy **altering** the solution (to our specific needs)
>
> I was busy **adapting** the solution

Personnally I'd go with [Tweaking](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/tweak) ;  Collins.

> (informal) to make a minor alteration

Comment: None of these words pass on the intention of getting the solution to actually work.

Comment: The question is not clear. "Getting an existing solution to work" . If it's a solution, by definition it is supposed to work, or it would not be a solution, it'd be a try, a test, a partial answer... whatever but not a solution.  A solution is something that solves a problem practically or theoretically : all it needs is to be applied. Or if it's applied to a similar problem we can  fine tune or tweak it  and still call that a solution, but only because it's very close to solving the problem. What you describe is more akin to recycling.

Answer (score 1):

In the software world, *[porting](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/8925/porting)* is the term usually used for this activity.

> I was busy *porting* the solution company X gave us [to work in our
>   environment and on our hardware].

To use a [real-world example](https://sourceforge.net/projects/irix-software/?source=directory):

> The IRIX Software Project is an initiative to **port** open-source
>   software to the IRIX operating system running on Silicon Graphics
>   workstations.

From the definition:

> Porting is the process of adapting software in an environment for
>   which it was not originally written or intended to execute in. The
>   term is used interchangeably when referring to the changes made to
>   hardware when it has to be made compatible with other environments.

Answer (score 0):

'***Jugaad***' is a colloquial Hindi word which is now being extensively used in English in India. It means 'an innovative solution usually frugal, a workaround'.

I was busy thinking of a jugaad for the Company X's problem.

Comment: It's not English, but you will find it in many Indian english writings.  The popularity of this word, I think, can be attributed to a lack of better word in English.

Comment: **Jugaad** is the Indian equivalent of "There, I fixed it" type of innovative workarounds with whatever (minimal) resources available at hand. It's hard to imagine how it would fit OP's context in any possible way...

Comment: It sounds like a word English needs.  How do you pronounce it?  Is it a made-up word in Hindi -- how did it come to be?

Comment: I think that's a "hack" in the US.